# Android Espresso test with test data input

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

As part of our test automation, I want to create some test accounts/data and then feed these values to a test config file. This config file which contains details like user credentials needs to be used within the Espresso tests.

How can I do this with Espresso?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've implemented the enum for user data as below:

```
    public enum UserData {
        testUser1("email1@email.com", "password", "Name", "Surname"),
        testUser2("email2@email.com", "password", "Name", "Surname");

        private String email;
        private String password;
        private String name;
        private String surname;

        UserData(final String email, final String password, final String name, final String surname) {
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getDisplayName() {
            return this.name + " " + this.surname;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return this.surname;
        }
    }
```

Then you can import this class to you test class and access any user data:

```
import com.your.app.test.UserData;
```

And test itself:

```
@Test
public void simpleTest() {
    onView(withId(R.id.edit_text_field))
        .perform(typeText(UserData.testUser1.getEmail()), closeSoftKeyboard());
    //do other stuff
}
```

Comment: This still picks data from the code. I want to use it from a config file